# Skiable upslope area of specific point on DEM using QGIS

Tags: qgis, dem, upstream

I am looking for a way to determine the area above a point that can be reached by only walking up or horizontally.

Or in a bit more technical terms, I am looking for an algorithm that starts a specific point on a raster and then checks if its neighbours are higher or equally high. If yes, the procedure will be repeated from there, if not, they'll be discarded.
Optimally there would even be a way, so that I could say, only cells which are at least (e.g.) 5 deg. higher can be reached.

I've thought about using some hydrological tools, but I think, the area will be much larger than just the area contributing to the runoff at that point.

Any hints on how to proceed with this task?

Comment: What about SAGA upsloape area tool, accessible in QGIS? See: https://saga-gis.sourceforge.io/saga_tool_doc/7.1.1/ta_hydrology_4.html

Comment: hey @Babel, i've tried that one, but it really only gets the cells which contribute to the inflow of the start cell. so in fact, i think it should be called upstream, rather.

Answer (score 1):

I used [Path Distance Allocation](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/path-distance-allocation.htm) tool with this settings for vertical factor:

[image]

OUTPUT:

[image]

So, it is doable, try to find same tool in QGIS.